# What's the point of malloc(0)?

Tags: c, malloc

I just saw this [code:](https://github.com/mxcl/scrobsub/blob/2ad2f6131e5900d4c62d8c5bcdb15c069f17e3bd/scrobsub.c#L94)

```
artist = (char *) malloc(0);
```

...and I was wondering why would one do this?

Comment: related :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073157/zero-size-malloc

Answer (score 158, accepted):

According to the specifications, [malloc(0)](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) will return either "a null pointer or a unique pointer that can be successfully passed to free()".

This basically lets you allocate nothing, but still pass the "artist" variable to a call to free() without worry.  For practical purposes, it's pretty much the same as doing:

```
artist = NULL;
```

Comment: Personally, I think setting to NULL is a better cross-platform strategy, since free() is guaranteed (by spec) to work fine on NULL as input.

Comment: As mentioned by C. Ross, some platforms, technically, could return a pointer here (that is a "unique pointer that can be passed to free"), but if you're treating this as a char*, that may give you an invalid, non-terminated char.  It could be dangerous to rely on this in cross-platform situations.

Comment: Note that this also happens when you declare an empty struct where `sizeof` will return `0`.

Comment: Really wish the specs would say "safely passed to realloc" as well -.-

Comment: @NSAddict "empty struct where sizeof will return 0", please provide an example, sounds like a language extension.

Comment: @chux `struct fred {};`?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Interesting, when I compile I get " warning: struct has no members [-Wpedantic]" with `struct fred {};`.  Does your compiler raise any flags?

Comment: @chux I haven't tried it. However, `-Wpedantic` shows warnings for _everything_ pointless or silly. (The impressive ones are when you try to golf in C.)

Comment: Were there any ancient C compilers that did not properly handle `NULL` on calls to `free`? If so, that would make code like what op posted make more sense to me along with code I've seen littered through legacy codebases like: `if (ptr) free(ptr);` -- otherwise all such code seems pointless, wasteful, and maybe naive about standard behavior.... but if such compilers/library implementations of `free` ever existed that failed to handle `NULL` properly in some distant past, then such code would make so much more sense.

Comment: @hanshenrik Who says you can't? [`realloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html) allows you to pass any valid pointer returned by `malloc()`. Should be enough.

Answer (score 62):

The C standard (C17 7.22.3/1) says:

> If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation defined:
>   either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some
>   nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

So, `malloc(0)` could return `NULL` or a valid pointer *that may not be dereferenced*.  In either case, it's perfectly valid to call `free()` on it.

I don't really think `malloc(0)` has much use, except in cases when `malloc(n)` is called in a loop for example, and `n` might be zero.

Looking at the code in the link, I believe that the author had two misconceptions:

- `malloc(0)` returns a valid pointer *always*, and
- `free(0)` is bad.

So, he made sure that `artist` and other variables always had some "valid" value in them.  The comment says as much: `// these must always point at malloc'd data`.

Comment: The fact that it is implementation dependent makes it more or less completely useless - this is one of the crappier bits of the C standard, and quite a few of the standards comittee (for example P.J. Plauger) have moaned about it.

Comment: I agree.  If `malloc(0)` returned a valid pointer, then `malloc()` returning `NULL` means "failure" always, and `0` isn't a special case anymore, which is more consistent.

Comment: Since the circumstances of `malloc` failure to obtain memory are implementation-defined, an implementation could simply define that size-0 allocations are always unsatisfiable (`ENOMEM`), and now `malloc(0)` returning 0 (with `errno==ENOMEM`) is consistent. :-)

Comment: Why would free(0) be bad ?

Comment: @Antzi it isn't bad.  `free(0)` is a no-op.

Comment: Can you `realloc` a pointer returned by `malloc(0)`? Can you `realloc((char*)NULL)`?

Comment: @Braden Best Yes to both.

Comment: At one time, free(0) was a crash.

Answer (score 13):

malloc(0) behaviour is implementation specific. The library can return NULL or have the regular malloc behaviour, with no memory allocated. Whatever it does, it must be documented somewhere.

Usually, it returns a pointer that is valid and unique but should NOT be dereferenced. Also note that it CAN consume memory even though it did not actually allocate anything.

It is possible to realloc a non null malloc(0) pointer.

Having a malloc(0) verbatim is not much use though. It's mostly used when a dynamic allocation is zero byte and you didn't care to validate it.

Comment: `malloc()` must keep "housekeeping information" somewhere (this size of the block allocated for example, and other auxiliary data).  So, if `malloc(0)` does not return `NULL`, it will use memory to store that information, and if not `free()`d, will constitute a memory leak.

Comment: Malloc implementations perform record keeping which could add a certain amount of data per pointer returned on top of the size  requested.

Comment: Memory consumed and memory allocated does not mean the same thing.  In this very case, most implementation will return a unique pointer. This mean a part of the address space needs to be sacrificed for that pointer. Depending on the allocator, this might actually mean it will allocate 1 byte or more.

Comment: @jldupont: In practice if an implementation does take this option, then it's because it has gone through all the motions of doing an allocation, but with size 0. The overhead will be the same as for any other allocation. Even if it did something different, it would still have to reserve some address space, and make a record somewhere that it has done so.

Comment: @Steve: of course... but which implementation would do this anyways?

Comment: *The library can do whatever it wants* - well, it can either return a unique pointer that no other `malloc()` will return, or return `NULL`.

Comment: @jldupont: you want a list of memory allocators which return non-NULL for `malloc(0)`? I don't know, sorry, it's not something I've ever felt the need to rely on. I wouldn't consider it unreasonable, though: returning NULL in this case is basically an early-out speed optimisation, for a case that probably never happens. Waste of good ASCII characters, unless your allocation code would special-case 0 anyway.

Comment: @Steve: I was just curious, that's all. Thanks.

Comment: @jldupont: At least the Microsoft C Run-Time library returns a unique pointer for `malloc(0)`. However, in the very same implementation of the standard C library, `realloc(ptr, 0)` frees `ptr` and returns NULL.

Answer (score 7):

There's an answer elsewhere on this page that begins "malloc(0) will return a valid memory address and whose range will depend on the type of pointer which is being allocated memory".  This statement is incorrect (I don't have enough reputation to comment on that answer directly, so can't put this comment directly under there).

Doing malloc(0) will *not* automatically allocate memory of correct size.  The malloc function is unaware of what you're casting its result to.  The malloc function relies purely on the size number that you give as its argument.  You need to do malloc(sizeof(int)) to get enough storage to hold an int, for example, not 0.

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of half true answers around here, so here are the hard facts. The man-page for `malloc()` says:

> If size is 0, then malloc() returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be
>          successfully passed to free().

That means, there is absolutely no guarantee that the result of `malloc(0)` is either unique or not NULL. The only guarantee is provided by the definition of `free()`, again, here is what the man-page says:

> If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed.

So, whatever `malloc(0)` returns, it can safely be passed to `free()`. But so can a `NULL` pointer.

**Consequently, writing** `artist = malloc(0);` **is in no way better than writing** `artist = NULL;`

Comment: Too bad the implementation isn't allowed to return a non-null, non-unique pointer. That way, `malloc(0)` could return, say, 0x1, and `free()` could have a special-case check of 0x1 just as it has for 0x0.

Comment: `man` may as well document the implementation-defined form used in *nix. In this case it doesn't, but it still isn't a canonical source for general C.

Comment: @Lundin True. But the man-pages are much more accessible than the C standard, and the man-pages on GNU/Linux systems generally document quite well which standard(s) the implementation follows. Along with information of which parts adhere to which standard, should they differ. I have the feeling that they both want to be precise, and advertise every single bit that's a GNU extension...

Answer (score 3):

`malloc(0)` doesn't make any sense to me, unless the code is relying on behaviour specific to the implementation. If the code is meant to be portable, then it has to account for the fact that a NULL return from `malloc(0)` isn't a failure. So why not just assign NULL to `artist` anyway, since that's a valid successful result, and is less code, and won't cause your maintenance programmers to take time figuring it out?

`malloc(SOME_CONSTANT_THAT_MIGHT_BE_ZERO)` or `malloc(some_variable_which_might_be_zero)` perhaps could have their uses, although again you have to take extra care not to treat a NULL return as a failure if the value is 0, but a 0 size is supposed to be OK.

Answer (score 3):

Why you shouldn't do this...

Since malloc's return value is implementation dependent, you may get a NULL pointer or some other address back. This can end up creating heap-buffer overflows if error handling code doesn't check both size and returned value, leading to stability issues (crashes) or even worse security issues.

Consider this example, where further accessing memory via returned address will corrupt heap iff size is zero and implementation returns a non NULL value back.

```
size_t size;
 
/* Initialize size, possibly by user-controlled input */
 
int *list = (int *)malloc(size);
if (list == NULL) {
  /* Handle allocation error */
}
else {
  /* Continue processing list */
}
```

See [this Secure Coding page](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MEM04-C.+Beware+of+zero-length+allocations) from CERT Coding Standards where I took the example above for further reading.

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly, I have never seen this before, this is the first time I've seen this syntax, one could say, a classic case of function overkill. In conjunction to Reed's answer, I would like to point out that there is a similar thing, that appears like an overloaded function `realloc`:

- foo is non-NULL and size is zero, `realloc(foo, size);`. When you pass in a non-NULL pointer and size of zero to realloc, realloc behaves as if you’ve called free(…)
- foo is NULL and size is non-zero and greater than 1, `realloc(foo, size);`. When you pass in a NULL pointer and size is non-zero, realloc behaves as if you’ve called malloc(…)

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows:

- `void *p = malloc(0);` will allocate a zero-length buffer on the local heap.  The pointer returned is a valid heap pointer.
- `malloc` ultimately calls `HeapAlloc` using the default C runtime heap which then calls `RtlAllocateHeap`, etc.
- `free(p);` uses `HeapFree` to free the 0-length buffer on the heap.  Not freeing it would result in a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

The person who wrote the code likely wants you to think of `malloc(0)` as an empty initialized array to which values are to be added (`realloc()`). While [this works regardless of whether `malloc(0)` returns `NULL` or an actual pointer](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html), it spawns ground for misunderstanding:

Without implementation-awareness, you won't be able to tell what a potential `NULL` returned by `malloc(0)` means. It could mean that you are out of memory, but it could also mean that that's what the implementation decides to return for allocations of size 0. Even if this is inconsequential to what your code does, it can raise some eyebrows.

This means that `malloc(0)` is an **attempt** at writing more readable code. However, due the fact that it engages implementation-specific behavior, losing information in the process, it is likely to cause confusion instead. Do not use it unless you specifically require the result of the implementation-specific behavior.

Comment: So how do you *portably* handle checking for failure if you call `malloc(0)`?  if you use `malloc(0)` **at all**, `malloc()` returning `NULL` loses all special meaning as an error condition.  That's the exact opposite of "higher-level language programmer" - your code **lost** information and you now have to write extra code to paper over that.

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. Using `malloc(0)` like this is un-idiomatic. I'm not sure what the point of _"deflects responsibility"_ is; using the result of `malloc(0)` doesn't exactly assign a proper value any more than assigning `NULL` (less so since the assigned value is implementation-defined for `malloc(0)`), and certainly it deflects the responsibility of checking for allocation errors to a possible later call to `realloc`. I don't see anything _"higher-level"_ about this; it seems like a mess.

Comment: I have rewritten my answer to reflect your criticism. Please mind I want the answer to stand out in that it pictures a line of reasoning based on developer idiosyncrasy rather than what the code actually does.

Answer (score -1):

To actually answer the question made: **there is no reason to do that**

Answer (score -2):

Not sure, according to some [random malloc source](http://www.raspberryginger.com/jbailey/minix/html/lib_2ansi_2malloc_8c-source.html) code I found, an input of 0 results in a return value of NULL. So it's a crazy way of setting the artist pointer to NULL.

http://www.raspberryginger.com/jbailey/minix/html/lib_2ansi_2malloc_8c-source.html

Answer (score -2):

Its actually quite useful, and (obviously IMHO), the allowed behavior of returning a NULL pointer is broken. A dynamic pointer is useful not only for what it points at, but also the fact that it's address is unique. Returning NULL removes that second property. All of the embedded mallocs I program (quite frequently in fact) have this behavior.

Comment: Could you give an example of when this is useful?

Comment: So why don't you `malloc(1)` then? That would return a unique address (at least unique within the lifetime of the allocated object).

Comment: PS: I doubt that your use case was a realistic use case in the time that `malloc` was "invented".

Answer (score -3):

malloc(0) will return NULL or a valid pointer which can be rightly passed to free. And though it seems like the memory that it points to is useless or it can't be written to or read from, that is not always true. :)

```
int *i = malloc(0);
*i = 100;
printf("%d", *i);
```

We expect a segmentation fault here, but surprisingly, this prints 100! It is because malloc actually asks for a huge chunk of memory when we call malloc for the first time. Every call to malloc after that, uses memory from that big chunk. Only after that huge chunk is over, new memory is asked for.

Use of malloc(0): if you are in a situation where you want subsequent malloc calls to be faster, calling malloc(0) should do it for you (except for edge cases).

Comment: Writing to `*i` may not crash in your case, but it's undefined behavior nevertheless. Watch out for nasal demons!

Comment: Yes. That is true. It is implementation specific. I have verified it on MaxOS X and some Linux distribution. I have not tried it on other platforms.

Having said that, the concept that I have described has been described in the book "The C programming language" by Brain Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie.

Comment: I know: super late comment on this question. But there is _sometimes_ a use for `malloc(0)` that isn't mentioned.  On those implementations where it returns a non-NULL value, especially in a DEBUG build, it likely allocates MORE than you asked for, and gives you the pointer to just past its internal header. This allows you to get a _feel_ for actual memory usage if you get this before and after a series of allocations.  e.g.: `void* before = malloc(0); ... void* after = malloc(0); long long total = after - before;` or some such.

Comment: I read "The C programming language" by Brain Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie and I don't remember it saying anything about `malloc(0)`. Could you please say which chapter are you referring too? Providing an exact quote would be nice too.

Comment: *but surprisingly, this prints 100!*  Ouch.  And how do you know your simple toy program didn't corrupt the heap in a way that won't be apparent in a program that immediately exits after the assignment to an invalid pointer?

Answer (score -3):

Here is the analysis after running with valgrind memory check tool.

```
==16740== Command: ./malloc0
==16740==
p1 = 0x5204040
==16740==
==16740== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16740==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16740==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,024 bytes allocated
==16740==
==16740== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

and here's my sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   //int i;
   char *p1;

   p1 = (char *)malloc(0);
   printf("p1 = %p\n", p1);

   free(p1);

   return 0;

}
```

By default 1024 bytes is allocated. If I increase the size of malloc, the allocated bytes will increase by 1025 and so on.

Comment: its implementation dependant

Answer (score -7):

According to [Reed Copsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65358/reed-copsey) answer and the man page of malloc , I wrote some examples to test. And I found out malloc(0) will always give it a unique value. 
See my example :

```
char *ptr;
if( (ptr = (char *) malloc(0)) == NULL )
    puts("Got a null pointer");
else
    puts("Got a valid pointer");
```

The output will be "Got a valid pointer", which means `ptr` is not null.

Comment: Just because you always got a valid pointer does not mean that it is guaranteed.

Answer (score -7):

Just to correct a false impression here:

`artist = (char *) malloc(0);` will never ever return `NULL`; it's not the same as `artist = NULL;`. Write a simple program and compare `artist` with `NULL`. `if (artist == NULL)` is false and `if (artist)` is true.

Comment: The C standard allows it to return NULL, but does not require it.

Answer (score -9):

`malloc(0)` will return a valid memory address and whose range will depend on the type of pointer which is being allocated memory. Also you can assign values to the memory area but this should be in range with the type of pointer being used. You can also free the allocated memory. I will explain this with an example:

```
int *p=NULL;
p=(int *)malloc(0);
free(p);
```

The above code will work fine in a `gcc` compiler on Linux machine. If you have a 32 bit compiler then you can provide values in the integer range, i.e. -2147483648 to 2147483647. Same applies for characters also. Please note that if type of pointer declared is changed then range of values will change regardless of `malloc` typecast, i.e.

```
unsigned char *p=NULL;
p =(char *)malloc(0);
free(p);
```

`p` will take a value from 0 to 255 of char since it is declared an unsigned int.

Comment: Krellan is right in pointing out that this answer is wrong: `malloc()` does not know anything about the cast (which is actually entirely superfluent in C). Dereferencing the return value of `malloc(0)` will invoke undefined behavior.