# What does malloc(0) return?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, malloc, realloc

What does `malloc(0)` return?

Would the answer be same for `realloc(malloc(0),0)`?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int main()
{
        printf("%p\n", malloc(0));
        printf("%p\n", realloc(malloc(0), 0));
        return 0;
}
```

Output from Linux GCC:

```
manav@manav-workstation:~$ gcc -Wall mal.c
manav@manav-workstation:~$ ./a.out
0x9363008
(nil)
manav@manav-workstation:~$
```

The output keep changing everytime for `malloc(0)`. Is this a standard answer? And why would anyone be interested in getting such a pointer, other than academic research?

**EDIT:**

If `malloc(0)` returns dummy pointer, then how does following works:

```
int main()
{
    void *ptr = malloc(0);
    printf("%p\n", realloc(ptr, 1024));
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

The following code outputs "possible" for every iteration. Why should it not fail ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int main()
{

        int i;
        void *ptr;
        printf("Testing using BRUTE FORCE\n");
        for (i=0; i<65000; i++)
        {
                ptr = malloc(0);
                if (ptr == realloc(ptr, 1024))
                        printf("Iteration %d: possible\n", i);
                else
                {
                        printf("Failed for iteration %d\n", i);
                        break;
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: @tommieb75: it helps to have answered the original question.  Having said that, this question has two parts, and the second part is more interesting and not a dupe.  See my answer to this question for details.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Others have answered how `malloc(0)` works.  I will answer one of the questions that you asked that hasn't been answered yet (I think).  The question is about `realloc(malloc(0), 0)`:

> What does `malloc(0)` return? Would the answer be same for `realloc(malloc(0),0)`?

The standard says this about `realloc(ptr, size)`:

- if `ptr` is `NULL`, it behaves like `malloc(size)`,
- otherwise (`ptr` is not `NULL`), it deallocates the old object pointer to by `ptr` and returns a pointer to a new allocated buffer.  But if `size` is 0, C89 says that the effect is equivalent to `free(ptr)`.  Interestingly, I can't find that statement in C99 draft (n1256 or n1336).  In C89, the only sensible value to return in that case would be `NULL`.

So, there are two cases:

- `malloc(0)` returns `NULL` on an implementation.  Then your `realloc()` call is equivalent to `realloc(NULL, 0)`.  That is equivalent to `malloc(0)` from above (and that is `NULL` in this case).
- `malloc(0)` returns non-`NULL`.  Then, the call is equivalent to `free(malloc(0))`.  In this case, `malloc(0)` and `realloc(malloc(0), 0)` are *not* equivalent.

Note that there is an interesting case here: in the second case, when `malloc(0)` returns non-`NULL` on success, it may still return `NULL` to indicate failure.  This will result in a call like: `realloc(NULL, 0)`, which would be equivalent to `malloc(0)`, which may or may not return `NULL`.

I am not sure if the omission in C99 is an oversight or if it means that in C99, `realloc(ptr, 0)` for non-`NULL` `ptr` is not equivalent to `free(ptr)`.  I just tried this with `gcc -std=c99`, and the above is equivalent to `free(ptr)`.

*Edit*: I think I understand what your confusion is:

Let's look at a snippet from your example code:

```
ptr = malloc(0);
if (ptr == realloc(ptr, 1024))
```

The above is not the same as `malloc(0) == realloc(malloc(0), 1024)`.  In the second, the `malloc()` call is made twice, whereas in the first, you're passing a previously allocated pointer to `realloc()`.

Let's analyze the first code first.  Assuming `malloc(0)` doesn't return `NULL` on success, `ptr` has a valid value.  When you do `realloc(ptr, 1024)`, `realloc()` basically gives you a new buffer that has the size 1024, and the `ptr` becomes invalid.  A conforming implementation may return the same address as the one already in `ptr`.  So, your `if` condition may return true.  (Note, however, looking at the value of `ptr` after `realloc(ptr, 1024)` may be undefined behavior.)

Now the question you ask: `malloc(0) == realloc(malloc(0), 1024)`.  In this case, let's assume that both the `malloc(0)` on the LHS and RHS returns non-`NULL`.  Then, they are guaranteed to be different.  Also, the return value from `malloc()` on the LHS hasn't been `free()`d yet, so any other `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()` may not return that value.  This means that if you wrote your condition as:

```
if (malloc(0) == realloc(malloc(0), 1024)
    puts("possible");
```

you won't see `possible` on the output (unless both `malloc()` and `realloc()` fail and return `NULL`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    void *p1;
    void *p2;

    p1 = malloc(0);
    p2 = realloc(p1, 1024);
    if (p1 == p2)
        puts("possible, OK");

    /* Ignore the memory leaks */
    if (malloc(0) == realloc(malloc(0), 1024))
        puts("shouldn't happen, something is wrong");
    return 0;
}
```

On OS X, my code didn't output anything when I ran it.  On Linux, it prints `possible, OK`.

Comment: @Alok: Great job. I checked the condition on Linux if (malloc(0) == realloc(malloc(0), 1024). It is failing everytime !

Comment: When you say "failing", you mean the program above prints "shouldn't happen, something is wrong"?

Comment: "The standard says this about realloc(ptr, size): if ptr is NULL, it behaves like malloc(size), otherwise (ptr is not NULL), it deallocates the old object pointer to by ptr and returns a pointer to a new allocated buffer." I feel I should mention that `realloc` only performs a `free(ptr)` if the memory area had to be moved, and if id didn't, no deallocation is performed, simply an expansion. At least that's what I understand from the `man`-page. "If the area pointed  to  was moved, a free(ptr) is done."

Comment: In both C99 and C11, the section **J.3 implementation-defined behavior** contains:  *-Whether the calloc, malloc, and realloc functions return a null pointer or a pointer to an allocated object when the size requested is zero (7.22.3).* which means `realloc(ptr,0)` *is* allowed to return a valid (but not dereferenceable) pointer like `malloc(0)`.

Answer (score 36):

`malloc(0)` is **Implementation Defined** as far as C99 is concerned.

From **C99** [Section 7.20.3]

> The  order  and  contiguity  of  storage  allocated  by  successive  calls  to  the  **calloc,
>   malloc, and realloc functions is unspeciﬁed**.  The pointer returned if the allocation
>   succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object
>   and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated
>   (until  the  space  is  explicitly  deallocated).  The  lifetime  of  an  allocated  object  extends
>   from the allocation until the deallocation.  Each such allocation shall yield a pointer to an
>   object disjoint from any other object.  The pointer returned points to the start (lowest byte
>   address)  of  the  allocated  space.   If  the  space  cannot  be  allocated,  a  null  pointer  is
>   returned.  **If  the  size  of  the  space  requested  is  zero,  the  behavior  is  implementation-
>   deﬁned**:  either  a  null  pointer  is  returned,  or  the  behavior  is  as  if  the  size  were  some
>   nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

Comment: if a non-NULL pointer is returned, then what's it's usage? why would they implement such behavior ?

Comment: it doesn't make much sense to return a non-null pointer, but so does malloc(0); the specification leaves this one open so a compiler builder may choose not to handle malloc(0) specifically, so that all the other mallocs are a nanosecond faster (because the check for 0 is ommited)

Comment: Simplicity. In some cases, it may simplify the underlying runtime library if it doesn't have to have any special handling of this special case. :)

Comment: PJ Plauger (C Standard Committee member) in one of his articles said their were huge arguments about this, and in the end they chickened out and left it to the implementation.

Comment: @Manav: it might be used as a tag-pointer: it's a pointer that's definitely distinct from any other valid pointer and that's not NULL.

Comment: returning a non null pointer in the case of malloc(0) is consistent and helps distinguish it from the error case of returning NULL, which may be returned from any argument to malloc, e.g. malloc(4).

Comment: From C99 Section 7.20.3: "...,except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object." I am using the same pointer in realloc later, it may be possible that realloc returns the same pointer as malloc(0) for the allocated memory, like realloc(malloc(0), 1024). Can this scenario occur ?

Comment: Huge arguments about this.. christ, what the hell is the matter with people?

Comment: @Joachim: why would it be distinct from another pointer?  Sometimes implementations round all requests up to be a multiple of the machine word size, so `malloc(0)` and `malloc(2)` might both return pointers to a (say) 8-byte buffer.

Comment: @BlueRaja: that's their job, to argue the pros and cons of various proposals. In this case, always returning a null pointer is convenient for some people, whereas making a 0-sized allocation is convenient for others. The committee is *supposed* to consider both. Unfortunately the compromise they came up with only helps platform-specific code, and is useless to anyone trying to code portably.

Comment: @TMN: because "Each such allocation shall yield a pointer to an object disjoint from any other object."

Comment: From the linux source code of malloc, it seems they return a free pointer without checking the condition (len == 0). The return value is, retval = (void *) bdesc->freeptr; that's why a free pointer reference is returned. It seems going by the source code that NULL is returned in case of malloc(0) only when there is no enough memory left.

Comment: @Bill: I thought Joachim was implying that `malloc(0)` returned a special kind of pointer that was somehow distinguishable from pointers to non-zero-size storage.  I was simply pointing out that just because you ask for zero bytes off the heap doesn't mean that `malloc()` doesn't allocate anything.  I probably should have worded my last sentence to be "...pointers to (say) 8-byte buffers", to make it clear that pointers to separate regions were being returned.

Comment: @TMN: Ah, I think Joachim was saying that any two pointers `a` and `b` returned by malloc(0) will satisfy `a != b` . (Assuming malloc doesn't return NULL for malloc(0), of course.)

Answer (score 15):

In C89, malloc(0) is implementation dependent - I don't know if C99 has fixed this or not. In C++, using:

```
char * p = new char[0];
```

is well defined - you get a valid, non-null pointer. Of course, you can't use the pointer to access what it points to without invoking undefined behaviour.

As to why this exists, it is convenient for some algorithms, and means you don't need to litter your code with tests for zero values.

Comment: @Neil: `malloc(0)` is the same in C99.

Comment: @Alok: that's just plain false. C99 allows `malloc(0)` to return 0, and good implementations do so.

Comment: @R. I think the point is that C99 doesn't *require* implementations to return `0` or non-`0` for `malloc(0)`.

Answer (score 5):

C99 standard

> If the space cannot be allocated, a
>   nullpointer is returned. If the size
>   of the space requested is zero, the
>   behavior is implementation-defined:
>   either a null pointer is returned, or
>   the behavior is as if the size were
>   some nonzero value, except that the
>   returned pointer shall not be used to
>   access an object.

Answer (score 4):

The [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ansi/index.html) has [the following](http://c-faq.com/ansi/malloc0.html) to say:

> The ANSI/ISO Standard says that it may
>   do either; the behavior is
>   implementation-defined (see question
>   11.33). Portable code must either take care not to call malloc(0), or be
>   prepared for the possibility of a null
>   return.

So, it's probably best to avoid using `malloc(0)`.

Comment: But the same pointer returned by malloc(0), if not NULL, can be used by realloc() to point to some valid memory location. Like realloc(malloc(0), 1024);

Comment: @Manav: It actually works with NULL too, `realloc(NULL, 1024)` is the same as `malloc(1024)`

Comment: Can ever malloc(0) and realloc(malloc(0), 1024) return same pointers ???

if (malloc(0) == realloc(malloc(0), 1024) printf("possible");

Answer (score 4):

One point nobody cared to talk about yet, in your first program is that `realloc` with length 0 is the same thing as `free`.

from the Solaris man page:

> The `realloc()` function changes the size of the block pointed
>        to by `ptr` to `size` bytes and returns a pointer to the (possibly moved) block. The contents will be unchanged up  to  the
>        lesser  of  the new and old sizes. If `ptr` is `NULL`, `realloc()`
>        behaves like `malloc()` for the specified size. If `size`  is  `0`
>        and  `ptr` is not a null pointer, the space pointed to is made
>        available for further allocation by the application,  though
>        not returned to the system. Memory is returned to the system
>        only upon termination of the application.

If one doesn't know that it can be a source of bad surprise (happened to me).

Comment: Funny, I mentioned this in the duplicate question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022335/whats-the-point-in-malloc0/2133585#2133585

Answer (score 3):

See C99, section 7.20.3:

> If the size of the space requested is
>   zero, the behavior is
>   implementationdefined: either a null
>   pointer is returned, or the behavior
>   is as if the size were some nonzero
>   value, except that the returned
>   pointer shall not be used to access an
>   object.

This is valid for all three allocation functions (ie `calloc()`, `malloc()` and `realloc()`).

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends.
I checked the Visual Studio 2005 sources and saw this in the _heap_alloc function:

```
if (size == 0)
    size = 1;
```

I think that in many cases you may want a valid pointer, even when asking for zero bytes.
This is because this consistent behavior makes it easier to check your pointers because: if you have a non-NULL pointer it's OK; if you have a NULL pointer you probably have a problem.
That's why I think that most implementations will return a valid pointer, even when asking for zero bytes.

Comment: I've often seen a general adjustment like `size = (size+WORD_LEN)%WORD_LEN;`  This keeps the blocks in the heap word-aligned, which often improves access time (especially for block transfers).

Comment: The blocks in the heap will be more than word aligned in most systems; typically, all blocks will be aligned on a multiple of 8 bytes; many will be aligned on a multiple of 16 bytes.  The return value must be sufficiently well aligned for any use.  For many systems, that means that if it is used for a double, it must be aligned on a multiple of 8 bytes; for some systems, a long double may be 16 bytes, and so on.  And even though Intel chips may handle misaligned data, there is a performance penalty in doing so which malloc() et al should - and do - avoid.

Answer (score 0):

> If malloc(0) returns dummy pointer, then how does following works:
>
> `void *ptr = malloc(0);`
>
> `printf("%p\n", realloc(ptr, 1024));`

I don't know what you mean by "dummy pointer".  If `malloc(0)` returns non-NULL, then `ptr` is a valid pointer to a memory block of size zero.  The `malloc` implementation saves this information in an implementation-specific way.  `realloc` knows the (implementation-specific) way to figure out that `ptr` points to a memory block of size zero.

(How `malloc`/`realloc`/`free` do this is implementation-specific.  One possibility is to allocate 4 bytes more than requested and store the size just before the memory block.  In that case, `((int *)ptr)[-1]` would give the memory block size, which is `0`.  You should never do this from your code, it's only for use by `realloc` and `free`).

Comment: @user9876: "If malloc(0) returns non-NULL, then ptr is a valid pointer to a memory block of size zero."... How do you allocate a valid memory block of size 'zero' as you said in your post?

Comment: How does your user application do it?  You call malloc(0) (if you're on a system where that returns non-NULL).  How does the system implement that?  That's a bit like asking how you can have a file on disk with a size of zero.  It's still a valid file on disk, with all the usual metadata (directory entries etc), it just has a size of zero.