# Why does malloc(0) return valid memory address ? What's the use?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [what does malloc(0) return ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132273/what-does-malloc0-return)
>   [what’s the point in malloc(0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022335/whats-the-point-in-malloc0)

Why does malloc(0) return valid memory address ? What's the use ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If the size of the space requested
>   is 0, the behavior is
>   implementation-defined: the value
>   returned shall be either a null
>   pointer or a unique pointer.

Source: [`malloc`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) at The Open Group

Answer (score 2):

I guess the address is valid only if you want to use 0 bytes from it. The use would probably be not having to specially treat cases like:

```
char * foo = malloc(size);
// do something with foo
free(foo);
```

Comment: Well yes, but you have to handle a NULL return value anyway and any decent programmer will have a coherent value of size at this point or after the malloc...

Comment: However, it is also safe to pass `NULL` to [`free`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/free.html).

Answer (score 2):

It does not return a valid address.

The result of malloc(0) is implementation defined and therefore unreliable.

Some compiler implementations will cause it to return a NULL pointer, others may return some other value (but it still can't/shouldn't be used to access memory).

The memory cannot be used, (however it may require free()ing).

Comment: You are right that it is implementation dependant but malloc(0) returns either NULL or a VALID address (meaning that you can call free on it without a segfault). So it returns a valid address. But you are right to say that you shouldn't use it. Anyway as any decent programmer will have code correctly checking size, it is kind of pointless debate ;) I agree with che saying it can save some more specific checks ...

Answer (score 2):

It isn't mandated in C (but it is mandated for new in C++).  There are cases where objects have no state (and so have a null size) but their identity is important.  In such case having an allocator which returns valid and different objects for a size of 0 is needed if you need to allocate them dynamically.

Comment: +1 for the comment on object state. A pity such things are implementation dependant ...

Comment: As you said, since this is implementation-dependent, it's useless. If you want to use such an ugly method of identifying distinct zero-size objects, just pass `MIN(1,size)` to `malloc` and pat yourself on the back for wasting at least 16 bytes per identity.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine a use for that, but, it is probably the result of malloc's design: if it's easier to support it than to not support, it should be supported.

Just as it's okay to take asin(4), and it returns a complex number... oops no it doesn't...

Comment: You need casin for the result to be a complex.

Comment: What !? C does not support a complex type out of the box ? What a pity :-)

Comment: @neuro You will laugh but C does support complex out of the box. C99 requires compilers to implement 'complex' as a native type.

Comment: Ahah. Too long a time I have not coded in C :-) If I wait long enough, I will have introspection ;-)

Comment: C has a native complex type, but the `asin` function will not return such values. The `asin` *macro* in `tgmath.h` can, but only if you cast or otherwise promote `4` to a complex type before calling it.