# gcc: how is "implementation-defined" malloc(0) defined?

Tags: c, gcc, malloc

C standard (e.g. C99) tells that `malloc(0)` returns "a null pointer or a unique pointer that can be successfully passed to free()". Which of the two, is **implementation-defined**. (This has been asked on StackOverflow many times, e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132273/what-does-malloc0-return), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022335/whats-the-point-in-malloc0), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110588/why-does-malloc0-return-valid-memory-address-whats-the-use), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487183/malloc0-actually-works).)

My question is: how does GCC define it?

Comment: As whatever the C library on the target system provides?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC doesn't define it at all.  GCC uses the `malloc()` implementation provided by the standard library.  On OS X this will be libSystem, on Linux this will usually be glibc or eglibc, etc.  These libraries are open source, so you can browse the source code.

Comment: @Dietrich: Thank you! http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/glibc/master/view/head:/malloc/malloc.c#L117 says that "Even a request for zero bytes (i.e., malloc(0)) returns a pointer to something of the minimum allocatable size."