# Why is the return value of malloc(0) implementation-defined?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, malloc

ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 (i.e. the C99 standard), §7.20.3 states:

> If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined:
>   either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some
>   nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

In other words, malloc(0) may either return NULL or a valid pointer which I may not dereference.

What is the rationale behind this behavior?
And wouldn't it be easier to just define that malloc(0) leads to UB?

Comment: The one thing I never expected someone to argue C99 should have more of is undefined behavior.

Comment: @yes123: I can't see why you would, but you might call a malloc(n) without checking if n == 0.

Comment: Also read the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132273/what-does-malloc0-return/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [C99 Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) (PDF link) discusses the memory management functions (from C99 7.20.3) and explains:

> The treatment of null pointers and zero-length allocation requests in the definition of these functions was in part guided by a desire to support this paradigm:
>
> ```
> OBJ * p; // pointer to a variable list of OBJs
>     /* initial allocation */
> p = (OBJ *) calloc(0, sizeof(OBJ)); 
>     /* ... */
>     /* reallocations until size settles */
> while(1) { 
>     p = (OBJ *) realloc((void *)p, c * sizeof(OBJ)); 
>       /* change value of c or break out of loop */
> }
> ```
>
> This coding style, not necessarily endorsed by the Committee, is reported to be in widespread use.
>
> Some implementations have returned non-null values for allocation requests of zero bytes.
>   Although this strategy has the theoretical advantage of distinguishing between "nothing" and "zero" (an unallocated pointer vs. a pointer to zero-length space), it has the more compelling theoretical disadvantage of requiring the concept of a zero-length object.
>
> Since such objects Library cannot be declared, the only way they could come into existence would be through such allocation requests.
>
> The C89 Committee decided not to accept the idea of zero-length objects.  The allocation 
>   functions may therefore return a null pointer for an allocation request of zero bytes.  Note that this treatment does not preclude the paradigm outlined above.
>
> **QUIET CHANGE IN C89**:  A program which relies on size-zero allocation requests returning a non-null pointer will behave differently.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the above paradigm would still perfectly work if a request to allocate zero bytes would always result in a NULL pointer, since realloc(NULL, n) == malloc(n). To me, the above paradigm doesn't explain why it is necessary to have two possible return values of malloc(0).

Comment: Nevertheless, I think this will be the best answer we can get, so I'm accepting it.

Comment: @Philip:  The example at the beginning is the explanation for why the result is not undefined.  It will work whether null or some other pointer is returned, but it won't work if the results are undefined.  The explanation below is, I believe intended to be separate from the example, so the reason that either null or some other pointer are both allowed is that "some implementations have returned non-null values for allocation requests of zero bytes" but "The C89 Committee decided...the allocation functions may therefore return a null pointer for an allocation request of zero bytes."

Comment: In effect, @R.'s answer explains it well:  C wasn't standardized until there were a lot of implementations that in some cases had different behavior, so C90 was a "compromise" of sorts.

Answer (score 9):

Because allocating 0 bytes may actually have sense. For example, when you are allocating an array with unknown number of items. UB would allow the program crash, whereas with the current behaviour you can safely allocate `numberOfItems * itemSize` bytes.

The logic is following: if you ask for 0 bytes, you get a pointer back. Of course, you must not dereference it, as this would have accessed 0-th byte (which you haven't allocated). But you can safely free the memory afterwards. So you don't need to make 0 a special case.

This was about why not define `malloc(0)` as UB. About the decision not to define the result strictly (`NULL` vs. unique pointer to empty space) see James' answer. (In short: both approaches have their advantages and disadvantages. The idea of returning a unique non-null pointer is more compelling, but requires more conceptual work and puts more burden on implementors.)

Comment: I could also safely free the pointer if malloc(0) just returned NULL.

Comment: Yes, and this is allowed with whichever pointer is returned: NULL or non-NULL.

Comment: Having a `realloc` to size zero return a pointer for a minimal-sized allocation could sometimes be advantageous if a subsequent non-zero-sized request with the same pointer would be able to reuse the same space (if still available); if `realloc` can return non-null for a size-zero request, it makes sense to allow that for `malloc` as well.

Answer (score 5):

Making `malloc(0)` result in UB would be much worse. As it stands, you don't have to care what happens when the size is zero, as long as you're consistent about calling `free`.

The problem is that some existing implementations allocate a pointer for `malloc(0)`, some return null pointers, and almost all of them are adamant about sticking with their behavior because the same people who wrote the implementations wrote lots of bad, non-portable software that makes use of their chosen behavior (GNU being among the worst offenders in this area). Thus the standard got stuck allowing both behaviors to keep them all happy.

Comment: No references R..?! I agree with the symmetry of requiring `free`, I think this makes it "pure". Some links for a +1.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any links right off. I just know from my own experience that GNU software (via autoconf/gnulib) insists on testing if the system `malloc(0)` returns a non-null pointer, and does this hideous wrapping hack around it if it doesn't.