# Why does malloc(0) cause a major memory leak on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, memory-leaks

I have just concluded a happy 4.5 hours of debugging a nasty leak in my system.

It turns out I was doing this:

```
params = allocate(sizeof(Something*) * num_params);
```

which in turns essentially calls `malloc` with the first argument passed in. When `num_params` is 0, it would call `malloc(0)`.

Running this in a loop, the program would very quickly take up most of the memory. I fixed it by first checking if `num_params == 0`, and if so avoiding the call to `allocate`.

I know that the Standard dictates `malloc(0)` is implementation-defined. So, how is this implemented in the Windows 7 C runtime library, and why does it cause a leak?

**Edit:** Clarifying the question - why does `malloc(0)` on Windows allocate memory, and what is the logic that dictates how much memory will be allocated?

Comment: A memory leak is not related with malloc( 0 ). It can occur when you do not free the allocated memory allocated with malloc( 0 ).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I understand. Later on in the code I checked `if (num_params > 0) free_things();`. Assuming `malloc(0)` doesn't allocate anything. I assume the question would be why and how does `malloc(0)` allocate memory from the heap.

Comment: My assumption is that you don't free the memory because you think none was allocated (maybe you are storing and checking the size against zero). `malloc(0)` may still allocate memory that you have to free: ["Typically, the pointer refers to a zero-length block of memory consisting entirely of control structures."](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MEM04-C.+Beware+of+zero-length+allocations)

Comment: Note that it may very well be zero though. You may have allocated memory worth 0 bytes data + X bytes memory manager metadata. (For example, the metadata may contain the information what the data size is... zero in this case ^^)

Comment: When you allocate memory, there's a certain amount of overhead involved. So even allocating 0-bytes takes up memory.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? It would be nice to be able to experiment with this - and to ensure that the error isn't caused by some other, unrelated bug.

Comment: In short, whenever you call `malloc` you should *always* pass the returned pointer to `free`. Note that `free(NULL)` is perfectly valid, so you don't have to check for that.

Comment: But you do have to be careful about `realloc(0)`! See [this](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MEM04-C.+Beware+of+zero-length+allocations) too

Comment: OP says "Assuming malloc(0) doesn't allocate anything." It is quite clear in the [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/malloc?view=vs-2019). *If size is 0, malloc allocates a zero-length item in the heap and returns a valid pointer to that item.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc(0)` returns a new valid address because that's the option it chose among those the C standard permits.

> **7.22.3 Memory management functions** (emphasis mine)
>
> [1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3p1) The order and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls
>   to the aligned_alloc, calloc, malloc, and realloc functions is
>   unspecified. The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is
>   suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type
>   of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to
>   access such an object or an array of such objects in the space
>   allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated). The lifetime of
>   an allocated object extends from the allocation until the
>   deallocation. **Each such allocation shall yield a pointer to an
>   object disjoint from any other object**. The pointer returned points
>   to the start (lowest byte address) of the allocated space. If the
>   space cannot be allocated, a null pointer is returned. **If the size
>   of the space requested is zero, the behavior is
>   implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the
>   behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the
>   returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.**

The implementation on windows chooses the second behavior. And so it must do *some* allocation to ensure the requirement appearing immediately before. Each valid pointer returned by an allocation function must be disjoint from any other pointer returned by an allocation function.

---

Relevant reading:

- [Why is the return value of malloc(0) implementation-defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372591/why-is-the-return-value-of-malloc0-implementation-defined)

Comment: What's the motivation to implement the second behavior, is beyond me.

Comment: @TonyTannous - ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ But it might make for a good question if none exist already

Comment: @TonyTannous, that `malloc()` does not spurriously fail seems like a reasonable motivation for choosing the second option.  That is also the choice made by glibc.

Comment: I don't disagree with this answer, but I'm uncertain whether it constitutes a complete response to the question. The question seems to be saying that `malloc(0)` allocates *unreasonably large amounts* of memory for them, and it has been edited to ask specifically about the size of the allocation.

Comment: @john Bollinger interesting. I went to the documentation of malloc.c in glibc. 
`Minimum allocated size: 4-byte ptrs: 16 bytes (including 4 overhead) 8-byte ptrs: 24/32 bytes (including, 4/8 overhead) ` and `Even a request for zero bytes (i.e., malloc(0)) returns a pointer to something of the minimum allocatable size`

Comment: Ok, @TonyTannous.  That verifies my assertion that Glibc's `malloc` handles an argument of 0 by allocating rather than failing.  But you could have just gone to the manual for that, and the details of how much space Glibc's `malloc()` allocates are not relevant to the OP's situation.

Comment: @TonyTannous "What's the motivation to implement the second behavior, is beyond me." A possible answer: [the memory block can be modified later by realloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/allocating-zero-memory).

Answer (score 2):

Some systems simply return `NULL` without allocating anything. But it's perfectly legitimate for `malloc` to allocate a 0 byte block of memory and return a pointer to that memory. This block must be freed like any other allocated by `malloc`.

When you allocate memory, there's a certain amount of overhead involved. So even allocating 0 bytes takes up memory.

Also, systems may over-allocate or have have alignment restrictions that may render some memory unusable after each allocation. This may or may not happen here.

---

In the comments, you mentioned you are doing something along the lines of the following:

```
if (num_params > 0) {
    ...free elements of params...
    free(params);
}
```

Instead, you should have been doing the following:

```
if (params) {
    ...free elements of params...
    free(params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [man](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/malloc?view=vs-2019) page:

> If size is 0, malloc allocates a **zero-length item** in the heap and returns a valid pointer to that item

And, with the valgrind check for the small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *p = malloc(0);

    if(!p) {
        printf("%p\n", p);
    }
    //free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

We have the log:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==11874==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 1 blocks
==11874==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==11874== 
==11874== 0 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==11874==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
```

But with `free` function:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==11887==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11887==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==11887== 
==11887== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

Comment: That is Linux, not Windows. Please see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876053/why-does-malloc0-cause-a-major-memory-leak-on-windows#comment109441968_61876053).

Comment: sorry, about that. I add the link for description of malloc for window

Answer (score 0):

As others have quoted, **malloc(0)** is implementation defined, a null pointer is returned or the behaviour is as if the size were some nonzero value. Clearly it's the second option and quoting Microsoft's documentation for [malloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/malloc?view=vs-2019)

> If size is 0, malloc allocates a zero-length item in the heap and
>   returns a valid pointer to that item.

Doesn't specifiy the overhead.

---

To get a sense we can look at glibc implementation for malloc.c

> Even a request for zero bytes (i.e., malloc(0)) returns a pointer
>   to something of the minimum allocatable size

---

> Minimum allocated size: 
>  4-byte ptrs: 16 bytes (including 4 overhead)
>   
>  8-byte ptrs: 24/32 bytes (including, 4/8 overhead)