# Zero bytes lost in Valgrind

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind

What does it mean when Valgrind reports o bytes lost, like here:

```
==27752== 0 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 1,532
```

I suspect it is just an artifact from creative use of `malloc`, but it is good to be sure (-;

EDIT: Of course the real question is whether it can be ignored or it is an effective leak that should be fixed by freeing those buffers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this is a real leak, and it should be fixed.

When you `malloc(0)`, malloc may either [give you NULL, or an address that is guaranteed to be different from that of any other object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132273/what-does-malloc0-return).

Since you are likely on Linux, you get the second. There is no space wasted for the allocated buffer itself, but libc has to do some *housekeeping*, and that does waste space, so you can't go on doing `malloc(0)` indefinitely.

You can observe it with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  unsigned long i;
  for (i = 0; i < (size_t)-1; ++i) {
    void *p = malloc(0);
    if (p == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Ran out of memory on %ld iteration\n", i);
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

gcc t.c && bash -c 'ulimit -v 10240 && ./a.out'
Ran out of memory on 202751 iteration
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you allocated a block with 0 size and then didn't subsequently free it.