# Valgrind output Understanding

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, valgrind

```
==20420== 
==20420== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20420==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 1 blocks
==20420==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==20420== 
==20420== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
==20420== Checked 48,492 bytes
==20420== 
==20420== 0 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==20420==    at 0x400677E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==20420==    by 0x80483D8: main (jig.c:10)
==20420== 
==20420== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20420==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20420==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20420==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20420==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 1 blocks
==20420==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

See in my project I use malloc like this:

```
malloc(sizeof(some_structure) * some_expression);
```

at one point some_expression gives value 0 so indirectly i am doing

```
   malloc(0)
```

So when I am not going to malloc a single byte so I am not making free it but in that case valgrind shows memory leackage. Why?

**Edit :**

If I use like this:

```
char *a = malloc(0);
```

Then a is not NULL. So question is why not NULL? & Which address it stores?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zero bytes lost in Valgrind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498395/zero-bytes-lost-in-valgrind)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my `malloc(3)` manpage (Linux):

> If size is 0, then `malloc()` returns either `NULL`, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to `free()`.

So there's no guarantee that `malloc` is not allocating any space when you pass it 0, and you have to `free` the pointer that it gives you if it isn't `NULL`.

If `malloc` does not return `NULL`, you get a buffer that you can't use for anything, but since it has a unique address, `malloc` must have allocated at least one byte.

Maybe you'd want to replace the `malloc` call with one to

```
// like malloc, but guarantees NULL return value if n==0
void *malloc0(size_t n)
{
    return n ? malloc(n) : NULL;
}
```