# c freeing malloc(0)

Tags: c, malloc, free, zero

I am writing an application in c in which I'm allocating the memory needed for some arrays dynamically. I know that many of those arrays will need zero allocation. So, will there be a problem when I call free on them? eg`free(malloc(0 * sizeof(int)));`? I know my application compiles and runs ok on my machine, but can I rely on this? Cheers!

Comment: Do be aware that `malloc(0)` is [implementation defined](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2132318/922184).

Comment: @Mysticial: Yes, but you can `free` any result it returns (either a valid pointer or NULL), right?

Comment: What does this have to do with zero-initialization of arrays?

Comment: @FredLarson Correct, but if `malloc(0)` returns `NULL`, it could trigger out-of-memory checks that check for `NULL`.

Comment: @larsmans: Who said anything about zero initialization?

Comment: @FredLarson: the OP did, in the question.

Comment: @larsman: No, he referred to "zero allocation", which I take to mean an allocation of zero size, hence the question.

Comment: @FredLarson: oh, sorry, misread it. My eyes must be getting tired.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876053/why-does-malloc0-cause-a-major-memory-leak-on-windows (says that on Windows, `free` after `malloc(0)` is mandatory to avoid memory leak)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`malloc(0)` may (this is implementation-defined) return a null pointer, or may return a new pointer each time you call it. In either case, the return value is valid to pass to `free`, since `free(0)` is a no-op anyway. However, due to some **nasty** issues with detecting and handling failure of `realloc` and disagreements between ISO C and POSIX, I would strongly advise you **never** to pass size 0 to `malloc` or `realloc`. You can always simply add `+1` or `|1` to the end of the argument to `malloc`, and then you're certain to get a unique pointer (different from the null pointer or the address of any other object) every time you call it.

Another reason not to use `malloc(0)` is that you have to always check the return value of `malloc` to detect failure, whereas `malloc(0)` can return a null pointer on success. This makes all of your error checking code more complicated since you have to special-case the non-error case where the size argument was 0.

Answer (score 8):

You can safely `free(malloc(0))`.

from `man malloc`:

> If  `size` is `0`, then `malloc()`
>     returns either `NULL`, or a unique pointer value that can later  be  suc‐
>     cessfully passed to `free()`.

free:

> If `ptr` is `NULL`, no operation is performed

Comment: Ooops! So I can call `free()` safely but, when I call `malloc()` I do check for the result too like: `if(!(arr = malloc(0))){ start screaming!}`... If `malloc(0)` is implementation dependent, this will fail, right?

Comment: Yeah, if you think `malloc()` returning `NULL` is an error then you can't call `malloc(0)`.  `malloc()` will set `errno` to `ENOMEM` on failure, so you can check that instead though.

Comment: To use `errno` here, you'd have to set it to 0 before calling `malloc`, and even then, it would be less reliable than I'd like. A better test would be just checking whether the size argument was 0 after `malloc` returns null, in which case it's not a failure.

Answer (score 1):

It is always legal to call `free` on the result of `malloc` (once).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `free(malloc(0))` is guaranteed to work.

For a further discussion, see [what's the point in malloc(0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022335/whats-the-point-in-malloc0)