# malloc(-1) returns NULL but malloc(0) doesn't why? how can you allocate 0 memory space

Tags: c, memory, null, malloc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what's the point in malloc(0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022335/whats-the-point-in-malloc0)
>   [what does malloc(0) return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132273/what-does-malloc0-return)

this code displays "unsuccesful" but if you replace  -1 with 0 it wont be NULL. I don't get how you can allocate 0 memory space. I know there's no use but isn't NULL == 0L so it should be == 0 too..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int *ptr;
if((ptr = malloc(-1)) == NULL)
    printf("unsuccessful: no memory space was allocated.\n");
else{
    printf("successful: memoryspace was allocated. \n");
    free(ptr);
}
getch();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: When `malloc` fails by returning `NULL` it should set `errno` and you should print `strerror(errno)`

Comment: "I don't get how you can allocate 0 memory space" - just don't call malloc() !!

Comment: Yeah, I was leaning towards multiple possibilities of allocating something (or maybe nothing) with one way of cleaning up. No need to check if `malloc` was called. It makes a bit more sense looking at it from a C++ class point of view, but I suppose it could happen in C.

Comment: not that im gonna use it. its a "what if" question.

Comment: *NULL == 0L* Not necessarily, no.  In C (not C++) NULL is typed as a pointer with the value of zero `(void *)(0)`, so don't fall into the trap of equating NULL with zero in all cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's implementation-defined:

> 7.22.3-1
>
> If the space cannot be allocated, a null pointer is returned. If the
>   **size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is
>   implementation-deﬁned**: either a null pointer is  returned,  or  the 
>   behavior  is  as  if  the  size  were  some  nonzero  value,  except 
>   that  the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

So it *can* return `NULL` but it doesn't *have* to. Also, to clarify why `malloc(-1)` fails, notice its prototype is:

```
void *malloc(size_t size);
             ^^^^^^
```

So you're converting `-1` to **an unsigned type**, yielding a very large value.