# Does malloc allocate more than I ask for?

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, malloc

The following code prints all the numbers between 1 and 300.
How come it does not throw throw a segmentation fault?

Compiled with:gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Also this is now different from [malloc(0) actually works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487183/malloc0-actually-works)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int *pi = (int *)malloc(1);
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0;i < 300;i++) {
    *(pi + i) = i + 1;
  }
  for (i=0;i < 300;i++) {
    printf("%d\n", *(pi + i));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: One of the possible manifestations of Undefined Behaviour is by the program doing what you expect. These are the toughest UBs to correct.

Comment: This is bad you should not do it. It will work only as expected as long as you are lucky.

Comment: @MohitJain I'd say **unlucky**

Comment: I know it is bad.I am curious as to why it almost always works.

Comment: It doesn't, it will cause memory corruption and unexplainable errors

Comment: Please read http://ericlippert.com/2014/05/07/why-does-my-code-not-crash/

Answer (score 1):

`malloc(0)` is implementation defined and returns either a null pointer or a pointer that must not be dereferenced.

Dereferencing the result of `malloc(0)` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: malloc(1) also works.

Comment: @user3004771 that is because the allocator usually gives your the smallest block it can work with, and that can be way more that 1 byte.

Comment: It works even with 400 integers.

Comment: page size in x86 is 4 kB

Comment: So if i ask for a byte, malloc returns at least 4kB?That seems like a waist.Indeed, it seems to work until 4000.

Comment: What malloc allocates is completely implementation-defined. However you can still get past that memory and it will not generate segmentation fault unless you cross the page boundary to cpu-unallocated region.

Comment: @user3004771 *undefined behavior*: It can crash or not. Or crash tomorrow or do whatever.

Comment: @ouah:So malloc retuns random-sized chunks of memory?I do not believe that.

Comment: @user3004771 *(C99, 7.20.3p1) "If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object."*

Comment: @user3004771: `malloc` formally allocates **exactly** what you ask for, and it formally returns a pointer to a memory block of that size. If it **really** allocates a few bytes more, that is incidential. The fact that your program does not immediately crash if you do something different because the hardware uses 4k pages and thus cannot detect your illegal use of memory at a granularity of a few bytes is circumstantial.

Comment: so malloc allocates at least what i ask for, but the difference is less than the cpu's page size?