# Error "cannot allocate memory block of size 67108864 Tb" in the R function false.nearest

Tags: r, chaos

The `R` function

```
tseriesChaos::false.nearest(series, m, d, t, rt=10, eps=sd(series)/10)
```

realizes the false nearest neighbours algorithm to help deciding the optimal embedding dimension.

I would like to apply it to the following series:

```
dput(x)
c(0.230960354326456, 0.229123906233121, 0.222750351085665, 0.230096143459004, 
0.226315220913903, 0.228151669007238, 0.225775089121746, 0.229447985308415, 
0.230096143459004, 0.232256670627633, 0.23722588311548, 0.236361672248029, 
0.231716538835476, 0.229231932591552, 0.229880090742141, 0.229447985308415, 
0.236901804040186, 0.234525224154694, 0.236577724964891, 0.240574700226855, 
0.238090093982932, 0.233552986928811, 0.235929566814303, 0.228799827157827, 
0.224694825537431, 0.225775089121746, 0.224694825537431, 0.221129955709193, 
0.214540347844874, 0.213352057902128, 0.21054337258291, 0.208706924489575, 
0.211083504375068, 0.212487847034676, 0.20903100356487, 0.206654423679378, 
0.213027978826834, 0.211083504375068, 0.216160743221346, 0.213244031543697, 
0.214324295128011, 0.216160743221346, 0.215512585070757, 0.218753375823701, 
0.215836664146052, 0.225126930971157, 0.228367721724101, 0.23128443340175, 
0.240574700226855, 0.244139570055093, 0.246732202657448, 0.248028518958626, 
0.246300097223723, 0.245976018148428, 0.241762990169601, 0.245976018148428, 
0.248892729826078, 0.258831154801772, 0.265744841741385, 0.259803392027655, 
0.258831154801772, 0.261855892837852, 0.262504050988441, 0.262071945554715, 
0.257102733066868, 0.270065896078643, 0.276655503942962, 0.280544452846495, 
0.280004321054337, 0.276547477584531, 0.286485902560225, 0.278924057470023, 
0.279140110186886, 0.272658528680998, 0.262828130063736, 0.26466457815707, 
0.254726153181376, 0.264448525440207, 0.261207734687264, 0.269741817003349, 
0.259587339310792, 0.256886680350005, 0.26163984012099, 0.252133520579021, 
0.257858917575888, 0.255158258615102, 0.252457599654316, 0.251701415145295, 
0.251161283353138, 0.251053256994707, 0.251917467862158, 0.24316733282921, 
0.242195095603327, 0.249540887976666, 0.259263260235497, 0.259263260235497, 
0.258399049368046, 0.252565626012747, 0.263800367289619, 0.262071945554715, 
0.259695365669223, 0.256886680350005, 0.253213784163336, 0.260127471102949, 
0.268769579777466, 0.271578265096684, 0.270173922437075, 0.267905368910014, 
0.262071945554715, 0.262936156422167, 0.261855892837852, 0.262720103705304, 
0.259047207518635, 0.263044182780598, 0.257102733066868, 0.259155233877066, 
0.259155233877066, 0.250297072485687, 0.24089877930215, 0.239494436642541, 
0.241546937452738, 0.24014259479313, 0.244355622771956, 0.242195095603327, 
0.242303121961759, 0.241438911094307, 0.236901804040186, 0.238954304850383, 
0.236793777681754, 0.239386410284109, 0.241546937452738, 0.24608404450686, 
0.244139570055093, 0.237333909473912, 0.238954304850383, 0.240250621151561, 
0.235281408663714, 0.234093118720968, 0.237657988549206, 0.246948255374311, 
0.249432861618235, 0.246516149940585, 0.247164308091174, 0.252997731446473, 
0.258399049368046, 0.258399049368046, 0.256238522199417, 0.268661553419034, 
0.275143134924922, 0.273630765906881, 0.270281948795506, 0.265204709949228, 
0.262071945554715, 0.258074970292751, 0.261747866479421, 0.260883655611969, 
0.264124446364913, 0.267257210759425, 0.271146159662958, 0.273954844982176, 
0.266933131684131, 0.269201685211192, 0.278383925677865, 0.278491952036297, 
0.271146159662958, 0.272982607756293, 0.27503510856649, 0.282921032731987, 
0.285297612617479, 0.285189586259047, 0.280436426488063, 0.287026034352382, 
0.288538403370422, 0.286593928918656, 0.287998271578265, 0.285081559900616, 
0.28464945446689, 0.279032083828454, 0.280112347412769, 0.278816031111591, 
0.281624716430809, 0.278491952036297, 0.2802203737712, 0.279896294695906, 
0.28097655828022, 0.276763530301394, 0.272550502322567, 0.276979583018256, 
0.292643404990818, 0.28907853516258, 0.291239062331209, 0.293615642216701, 
0.286918007993951, 0.287998271578265, 0.288322350653559, 0.280868531921789, 
0.274386950415901, 0.271146159662958, 0.278275899319434, 0.277411688451982, 
0.279140110186886, 0.28907853516258, 0.258939181160203, 0.256670627633142, 
0.25278167872961, 0.255698390407259, 0.261423787404127, 0.260559576536675, 
0.263692340931187, 0.260667602895106, 0.255158258615102, 0.257858917575888, 
0.250081019768824, 0.245219833639408, 0.24684022901588, 0.244895754564114, 
0.242195095603327, 0.246300097223723, 0.253861942313925, 0.253429836880199, 
0.264988657232365, 0.260235497461381, 0.258831154801772, 0.258831154801772, 
0.253213784163336, 0.249864967051961, 0.250081019768824, 0.245219833639408, 
0.249756940693529, 0.245651939073134, 0.24835259803392, 0.24835259803392, 
0.245867991789997, 0.248244571675489, 0.247056281732743, 0.249756940693529, 
0.248676677109215, 0.251593388786864, 0.254186021389219, 0.250837204277844, 
0.251593388786864, 0.248676677109215, 0.249540887976666, 0.251593388786864, 
0.242627201037053, 0.242519174678622, 0.240250621151561, 0.240034568434698, 
0.243059306470779, 0.244031543696662)
```

Hence, I used the code:

```
false.nearest(x, m=50, d=r, t=220, eps=1, rt=3)
```

Anyway, I obtained the error:

```
Error in false.nearest(x, m = 50, d = r, t = 220, eps = 1, rt = 3) : 
  cannot allocate memory block of size 67108864 Tb
```

I can't explain it, vector `x` has only 250 observations!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at `false.nearest` [source code](https://github.com/cran/tseriesChaos/blob/master/src/false.nearest.c) in `tseriesChaos` package:

```
/*
False nearest neighbours algorithm.
in_series: input time series (scaled between 0 and 1)
in_length: time series length
in_m, in_d, in_t: embedding dimension, time delay, theiler window
in_eps: neighbourhood size
in_rt: escape factor
out: fraction of false nearests
out2: total number of nearests
*/

void falseNearest(double *in_series, int *in_length, int *in_m, int *in_d, int *in_t, double *in_eps, double *in_rt, double *out, int *out2) {

double eps, *series; 
double dst;
double *dsts;
int *ids;
int m,d, t, length, blength;
int num, denum;
int i,j,md;
double rt;
int id;
boxSearch bs;

/*
BIND PARAMETERS
*/
    m = *in_m;
    d = *in_d;
    t = *in_t;
    rt = *in_rt;
    eps=*in_eps;
    series=in_series;
    length=*in_length;
/**/
/*
INIT VARIABLES
*/
    blength = length - m*d - t;
```

With your parameters set :

```
length. <- 250
m <- 50
d <- 3
t <- 220

(blength = length. - m*d - t)
[1] -120
```

`blength` is used as parameter to `R_alloc` and should be positive, otherwise sign bit will be [interpreted as a huge integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925771/what-happens-when-we-call-malloc-with-negative-parameter), causing memory allocation error :

```
dsts = (double*) R_alloc(blength, sizeof(double));
```

In this case, max value of `m`  to keep `blength` positive is `m=10`.

Constraints on parameters use are not documented in the package, nor does the package output an informative error message : reason for error is understood, but difficult to help further.