# malloc function in C

Tags: c, malloc

I've written the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* ch = malloc(0 * sizeof(char));
    int n = 300;
    sprintf(ch, "%d", n);
    printf("ch is : %s", ch);
    return 0;
}
```

I've switched the 0 in the malloc function to different numbers to experiment and I tried putting 0 meaning allocating no memory but when I run the program it worked just fine and I don't understand why is that exactly because if I put 0 it's like allocating no memory at all so what's happening here ?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, so you mainly got lucky. Here's an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022335/whats-the-point-in-malloc0

Comment: If you allocate zero bytes, `malloc` may return a valid pointer ***or*** it may return `NULL`. You still need to check for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`malloc(0)` is implementation-defined. It may return a null pointer, see [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ansi/malloc0.html) for detail.

The problem is in the following line:

```
printf("ch is : %s", ch);
```

`ch` is not a string (i.e, null-terminated char array), to print it with `"%s"` is illegal.

Comment: So how would you print it ?

Comment: But if I make it a char pointer doesn't it make it a string ? Then why would I make a char pointer and not an integer pointer for example ?

Comment: @AALC It's either a null pointer, nor a pointer to `0` sized memory. Either way, there's no way or no place for a legal string (at least one byte for `'\0'`).

Comment: The printf statement would be correct, assuming you had allocated enough space for the string representation of `n`, in this case 3 chars + a NULL.

Comment: @AShelly Sure it's correct **if** the space is enough. But that's not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

C lets you shoot yourself in the foot.

The malloc docs say

> If size is zero, the return value depends on the particular library
>   implementation (it may or may not be a null pointer), but the returned
>   pointer shall not be dereferenced.

So your implementation is returning something other than zero.  Your sprintf is writing into memory that it "shall not" write to.  But in this particular case, you got lucky, and it was nowhere critical - at least nowhere that mattered in this short test program. In a longer program with more mallocs and frees, you almost surely would run into trouble.