# Using malloc to allocated 0 bytes

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

So allocating zero bytes is ill-defined so I want to treat 0 bytes as a fail. Would this code do the trick

```
#include <stdio.h>
#incude "xmalloc.h"
void *malloc_or exit(size_t nbytes, const char *file, int line){
void *x; //declarea void pointer
if ((x = malloc(nbytes)) == NULL){
fprintf(stderr. " %s: line %d: malloc(%zu) bytes failed", file , line, nbytes);
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} else
return x;
}
```

Comment: Actually, for `malloc` to return 0 is not ill-defined; it is explicitly defined as the return value in case of error.

Comment: Allocating zero bytes may give you a valid pointer (which you can pass to `free`) or `NULL`, it's implementation defined. See e.g. [this `malloc` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `NULL` is also a valid pointer which you can pass to `free()` ;)

Comment: @Quentin Nitpicker... ;)

Comment: `void *x; //declarea void pointer`  - that's not how comments are supposed to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the link is to the N1570 draft) says:

> If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is
>   implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the
>   behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the
>   returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

So if your `malloc_or_exit()` function is called with an argument of `0`, it may either terminate your program (if `malloc(0)` returns `NULL`), or it may return a non-null pointer that may not be dereferenced (dereferencing such a pointer would cause undefined behavior).

If you want to treat a zero-sized allocation as an error, you can modify your wrapper function (untested):

```
void *malloc_or_exit(size_t size) {
    void *result;
    if (size == 0) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if ((result = malloc(size)) == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   int *p=(int*)malloc(0);
   p[0]=3;
   printf("%d",*p);
   return 0;
}

I tried this code and found no error which could be there due to dereferencing the pointer returned by malloc having 0 size as an argument.

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal Your code has undefined behavior. If it didn't show a visible error, that just means you have a bug that's difficult to detect.

Comment: actually, something is missing in the code, the dereferencing operator (star) is removed when I posted the code. I don't know why did it happen.

Comment: Please visit the below link and explain why is this running well(without any error)?

https://www.writeurl.com/text/pez4xzobzbo0l8zz7wdw/ar2eb1rh7zwpwziesyzq

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal Comments user markdown formatting. Asterisks are used for emphasis *like this*, double asterisks for bold **like this**. Use backticks to format text as code `like this`.

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal The link isn't working for me, but as I said the code in your original comment (once corrected for formatting errors) has undefined behavior. Behaving as you expect is one of the infinitely many possible consequences of undefined behavior (and arguably the worst). You're accessing an `int` object in unallocated memory. Remember that "undefined behavior" doesn't mean "this will crash". It means that the C standard says nothing about how it will behave.

Comment: Okay thanks for your suggestion, but I tried this code with `-pedantic` flag. Still can't figure out any warning.
Is there still any way through which compiler would raise a warning or just notify me about the undefined behaviour?

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/827263

Answer (score 1):

> If size is zero, the return value depends on the particular library implementation (it may or may not be a null pointer), but the returned pointer shall not be dereferenced.

ref:[malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/)

Comment: The "shall" in that is perhaps not helpful to the OP, who may not realize that it comes from the C standard.  Essentially it says that the program should not try to use the return value as a pointer because it is not guaranteed to be valid (or useful).

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 4;
void *x;
if( ( i != 0 ) && ( ( x = malloc(i) ) != NULL ) )
{
    // malloc successfull
}
else
{
    // not successfull
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

No - according to [whats-the-point-in-malloc0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022335/whats-the-point-in-malloc0), a non-null return value still may not be useful for your application.