# Difference between initializing a string with (char *)malloc(0) and NULL

Tags: c, string

Why allocating a 0 size `char` block works in this case?  But if I write `char *string = NULL;` it won't work.

I'm using Visual Studio.

```
int main()
{   
    char *string = (char *)malloc(0);
    string[0] = 'a';
    string[1] = 'b';
    string[2] = 'c';
    string[3] = 'd';
    string[4] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n",string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not "working"; it at best **pretends** to be working. Undefined behavior is called "undefined" and **not** "guaranteed crash" for a very good reason.

Comment: What did you expect to happen and why?

Comment: This is not at all a duplicate.

Comment: [Please don't cast the result of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3233393).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array index out of bound in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671703/array-index-out-of-bound-in-c)

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First let me state, as per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) of `malloc()`

> The `malloc()` function allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. The memory is not initialized. **If size is 0, then `malloc()` returns either `NULL`, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to `free()`.**

a call like `malloc(0)` is **valid** itself, but then, we need to check the validity of the returned pointer. It can either

- Return `NULL`
- Return a pointer which can be passed to `free()`.

but anyways, dereferencing that pointer is not allowed. It will cause out-of-bound memory access and cause  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, two important things to mention,

1. Please [see why not to cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.
2. Please check the return value of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.

So, to answer your question,

> *Difference between initializing a string with `(char *)malloc(0)` and NULL*

Do not use `malloc(0)` in this case, as a NULL check on the pointer *may* fail, giving the wrong impression of a *valid* allocation of the memory to the pointer. Always use `NULL` for initialization.

Answer (score 4):

The above code invokes undefined behavior. You have allocated insufficient memory and you are accessing invalid addresses.

According to the specifications, [malloc(0)](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html) will return either "a null pointer or a unique pointer that can be successfully passed to free()".

Comment: `s/random/invalid`. A memory allocator's behavior is pretty un-random, it would make a terrible PRNG.

Comment: @Quentin but this is a Q&A site for programmers, and if one gives an answer, one is supposed to phrase it correctly. I could as well decide that from now on, I use the word "string" to denote "function", and then I complain every time someone points out that one can't call a string that I just use "string" with "function" as its meaning. Some people are trying to use memory allocation addresses as the source of random numbers. Let's not encourage spreading the infection (what if these "random" numbers end up encrypting your HTTPS traffic? would you like that?)

Comment: @Quentin grow up. seriously, if you don't see the value in formulating correctly what one says, I don't even want to argue with you further.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I'm not even sure why you're arguing in the first place. Of course "invalid" is better than "random" for an indeterminate address. It's just that the thought of someone jumping on the mere presence of the word "random" and trying to make a PRNG out of it made me chuckle. There's no reason to be upset.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` definition:

> Allocates a block of size bytes of memory, returning a pointer to the
>   beginning of the block.
>
> The content of the newly allocated block of memory is not initialized,
>   remaining with indeterminate values.
>
> ***If size is zero, the return value depends on the particular library
>   implementation (it may or may not be a null pointer), but the returned
>   pointer shall not be dereferenced.***

Taken from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) and found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022335/whats-the-point-in-malloc0).

Comment: calling `malloc(0)` does not result in undefined behavior, and the returned address isn't particularly random either. (in particular, it is required to be unique.)