# In this C code how can the expression acts as the boolean

Tags: c

Basically I have two questions in the code bellow:

```
const char *x = "abc";
const char *y = "def";

char *res = (char*)malloc(0);
char *z = res;
while (*z++ = *x++);
z--; // remove \0
while (*z++ = *y++);

printf("%s\n", res); // output: abcdef
free(res);
```

The purpose of this code is to add two strings in one. But how this line `while (*z++ = *x++);` can act as `boolean` `1/0`, And why I even set the `malloc(0);` to zero it also works well without any problem??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022335/whats-the-point-in-malloc0

Comment: When you `malloc(0)`, even though it’s wrong, it happens to “work”. C doesn’t offer you any safety when making mistakes, generally, and is free to fail by pretending to work.

Comment: This is pure undefined behaviour. Bad bad code.

Comment: You need to malloc more than 0 space to rescue the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But how this line `while (*z++ = *x++);` can act as boolean 1/0

This is because in C, an assignment is an *expression* and it evaluates to the value that is assigned. When `*x` reaches the final `'\0'` terminator, it evaluates to `0`, therefore `false` in a boolean context.

This is btw a nice source of bugs due to mistyping:

```
if (x = 1) // always true, as a side effect assigns 1 to x
```

> And why I even set the `malloc(0);` to zero it also works well without any problem??

Using the return value of `malloc(0)` to write values is just undefined and "works by accident". You request *zero* bytes, so you are never allowed to write to this allocation and `malloc()` could even return you a *null pointer*.

Citing myself here about *undefined behavior*:

> #### Undefined behavior in `C`
>
> C is a very low-level language and one consequence of that is the following:
>
> *Nothing will ever stop you from doing something completely wrong*.
>
> Many languages, especially those for some *managed environment* like `Java`
>   or `C#` actually stop you when you do things that are not allowed, say,
>   access an array element that does not exist. `C` doesn't. As long as your
>   program is *syntactically* correct, the compiler won't complain. If you do
>   something forbidden in your program, `C` just calls the behavior of your
>   program **undefined**. This formally allows anything to happen when running
>   the program. Often, the result will be a crash or just output of "garbage"
>   values, as seen above. But if you're really unlucky, your program will seem
>   to *work just fine* until it gets some slightly different input, and by that
>   time, you will have a really hard time to spot where exactly your program is
>   *undefined*. Therefore **avoid undefined behavior by all means!**.
>
> On a side note, *undefined behavior* can also cause security holes. This
>   has happened *a lot* in practice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it was really very confusing to me. So it means that the expression also has a return value in C? which while loop can be stopped or run?

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Don't confuse the terms: An *expression* always has a *value*, this value is what the expression *evaluates* to. You might think that assignment is only a *statement* (something that's executed), but in C, it is *also* an expression, evaluating to the value that is assigned.

Answer (score 3):

In C, any expression can be used as a boolean. 0 (or null for pointers) means "false", non-zero means "true".

This even includes assignments. The expression is assigned, then evaluated.
So you can have code like

```
while(*dest++ = *src++);
```

This is the sort of thing that tends to give C a bad name, but it is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

To answer :

> But how this line while (*z++ = *x++); can act as boolean 1/0

This `while` loop will run until `*z` points to NUL, since the string literal contains "abc\0" this will loop over a, b, c then it will encounter `\0` which converts to `0` which will not satisfy the `while` and thus it terminates.

*Big big disclaimer though*:
This code is dereferencing a pointer that was obtained by `malloc(0)`, that is already very much undefined behaviour and thus there's no point in reasoning why this code works or doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

An assignment has a value, which is its left-hand side so:

```
a = b; // value of the expression is a, after the assignment
```

So `if(a = b){}` is like saying `a = b; if(a){}`.

In `C` any *non zero* numeric value or *pointer* equals *true* and only zero `0` or a *null pointer* is false.

So the expression `if(*x){}` is *true* if the `char` pointed to by `x` is any character except the *null terminator* character `'\0'`.

Putting it all together:

```
if(*x++ = *y++){}
```

Take the `char` pointed to by `y` and copy it to the `char` pointed to by `x`. Then increment both `x` and `y`. Execute the while body if that `char` was not the *null terminator* `'\0'`.

Sort of equivalent to:

```
*x = *y
exp = *x;
x++;
y++;
if(exp){}
```

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense of this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The condition

```
while (*z++ = *x++)
```

might be puzzling because of the expression concept of C which differs from some other languages. Note that strictly speaking, C does not have a boolean type. Furthermore, an assignment expression itself has a value, namely the assigned value.

Comment: C has, it is _Bool and aliased bool, if including stdbool.h - since C99...