# setting a character via index on a malloc char pointer not working

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, string-literals, char-pointer

```c
  char * s_string = malloc(0);
  s_string = "1234567";
  // s_string[7] = 'a'; // why not working ?...
  s_string = "123456a"; // but this works...
  printf("s_string = %s\n", s_string);
  s_string = "123412341234123412341234"; // does this do a realloc ?
```

when i try to set a single char i get a `145382 segmentation fault (core dumped)` but when i set the whole string with my char at the index, it works...
also , does setting a value of a char pointer with a literal value do a realloc on the char pointer ?
the code should explain my question...

Comment: The 2nd line overwrites the pointer returned from `malloc` ([What's the point of malloc(0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2022369)). At that point you are using string constants - and you can't write to that memory.

Comment: This code makes no sense. What do you think it *should* do? I'm really confused what your intention is here! What do you think does `malloc(0)` do? What `s_string = "1234567";` ?

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet

```
char * s_string = malloc(0);
s_string = "1234567";
```

produces a memory leak provided that the system indeed allocated memory instead of returning `NULL`.

That is at first memory was allocated and its address was assigned to the pointer `s_string` and then the pointer was reassigned with the address of the first character of the string literal `"1234567"`. So the address of the allocated memory was lost.

In this code snippet

```
s_string = "1234567";
s_string[7] = 'a'; // why not working ?.
```

you are trying to change the string literal pointed to by the pointer `s_string`. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

In this code snippet

```
s_string = "123456a"; // but this works...
printf("s_string = %s\n", s_string);
```

the pointer `s_string` was just reassigned with the address of another string literal.

In this statement

```
s_string = "123412341234123412341234"; // does this do a realloc ?
```

neither reallocation occurs. Again the pointer is reassigned with the address of another string literal and nothing more.

You may change the value stored in the pointer `s_string` because it is not a constant pointer.

For example if the pointer was declared like

```
char * const s_string = "1234567";
```

then the compiler would issue an error message for this assignment statement

```
s_string = "123456a";
```