# Free malloced memory in a library in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm learning C, and I gave myself a project to write a library to deal with .wav file.

I have this function where I malloc an array and return the pointer to the user. But I don't know what are the good practice to free the memory in this case.

```c
waveError waveReadSubchunk(FILE* file,uint8_t* id, uint8_t** data, uint32_t* size)
{
    uint16_t eof;
    uint32_t ckSize=0;
    uint8_t actId[4];
    *data = malloc(0);
    fseek(file,0,SEEK_END);
    eof = ftell(file);
    fseek(file,12,SEEK_SET);
    while(ftell(file)<eof && strncmp(id,actId,4)!=0){
        fseek(file,ckSize,SEEK_CUR);
        fread(actId,1,4,file);
        fread(&ckSize,4,1,file);
    }
    if (ftell(file)>=eof){
        return WAVE_INVALID_ID;
    }
    *data = realloc(*data,ckSize);
    fread(*data,1,ckSize,file);
    *size = ckSize;
    return WAVE_NO_ERROR;
}
```

For now I see two options:

- Be clear in the documentation that this is a dynamic allocation, so the user must free the memory by himself.
- Keep track of the pointer and write a cleaning function. Then tell the user that this cleaning function must be called at the end of the program.

The 1st solution seems easier but the responsability to free the memory is given to the user. I don't know if there is other option for those case and what is the best one.
What are your opinion on this?

Comment: Many libraries handles it by using some kind of *handle*, which is basically an [opaque structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type) that contains all the data needed internally by the library. This handle must be used for all functions, and there is a pair of "create handle" and "destroy handle" to handle things like allocations and destruction/cleaning.

Comment: If you want to write a Vanillia C library, I agree with the previous comment; you would write a handle struct that takes care of the (de)allocation. As a user of such a library, I would prefer a more object-oriented approach - which is even possible in C with structs (just a personal preference!).

Comment: OT: `*data = malloc(0);` and `*data = realloc(*data,ckSize);` why ? A single `*data = malloc(ckSize);` should do

Comment: @bouaaah,`uint16_t eof;` better as `long eof;` as `ftell(file)` returns a `long`.

Comment: It's quite common for you to simply note in the comment above your function that `/* The user is required to free memory allocated for data when that data is no longer required.*/` That is effectively what happens when you call `malloc()`. You need to ***Check the Return*** on every call you make that allocates memory. Otherwise, when the command fails returning `NULL` you will invoke undefined behavior blindly writing to the pointer without first checking it is not `NULL`...

Comment: This code uses `actId` without initialization it, and it has other problems that need to be addressed before being concerned about managing memory allocation.

Comment: If you write your own cleaning function, you don't need to keep track of what was returned by your allocation function. You can assume that the value passed to your cleaning function was returned by your allocation function and specify that passing any other values to your cleaning function (except for null pointer values, maybe) will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I wrote this function quickly and planned to add error checking afterward but this question came in my mind so i posted it as it was. I will update my post when I'll got time to modifiy it.

Answer (score 1):

> Be clear in the documentation that this is a dynamic allocation, so
> the user must free the memory by himself.

Yes, that's the way it is usually done.

> Keep track of the pointer and write a cleaning function. Then tell the
> user that this cleaning function must be called at the end of the
> program.

In this case, I do not see a need to write a wrapper around `free()`. Wrappers around memory deallocation functions might be more relevant in cases where a `struct` contains multiple members with dynamic memory allocations, making it useful to encapsulate the deallocation logic in a single function.

Though, in this case, I do suggest combining `size` and `data` into a single `struct`, and returning a pointer to it, and then providing a cleanup function that will deallocate the `data` field.

> The 1st solution seems easier but the responsability to free the
> memory is given to the user.

The responsibility to free the memory is given to the user in both cases. In the second case, the user is simply calling the cleanup function you have provided, assuming you do, in lieu of `free()`. There's no guarantee that the user would call either of them.

Note that setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has undefined behavior for a binary stream.

Also see: [What's the point of malloc(0)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2022335/20017547)

Answer (score 1):

It is okay for a simple “helper” routine to allocate memory and document that it does so and that the caller is responsible for freeing the memory. However, deciding to do that means there will be a burden of changing all uses of the routine if it ever graduates to being a more sophisticated interface.

If you start by designing an interface that encapsulates the data and methods, you can keep it lightweight at first (its “free” routine just calls `free` and could be defined inline in a header, although this requires exposing the data structure) and still be able to add to the interface later with little or no change to existing code that uses it.

However, your code has more serious issues.

In `while(ftell(file)<eof && strncmp(id,actId,4)!=0)`, `actId` is used before it is initialized. The behavior of this program is indeterminate.

You should detect end-of-file by testing the results of `fseek` and `fread` operations, not by attempting to measure the file size. Remove `uint16_t eof;` and all uses of `eof` from the code, and do not use `fseek` and `ftell` to attempt to determine the file size. One problem with this is that a file can be changed while a program is running so the file size you measure at one time might be different from the file size at the time you attempt to perform a read. Additionally, reads can fail for other reasons, so you need to check the result of every read operation. You cannot assume they succeed just because the read would be to a position earlier than the file size you measured previously.

So, your code should be changed:

- It is okay to do an `fseek` to skip the header or other initial data, but test the result of the `fseek` call and report an error if it fails.
- Change the `while` to a `do … while` to avoid using `actId` before it is initialized.
- Test the results of the `fseek` and `fread` calls in the loop and report an error if they fail or do not return all of the requested data.

Additionally:

- You do not need `*data = malloc(0);`. With the code you have, a later `*data = malloc(ckSize);` would be fine. If you did need to use `realloc` and wanted an initial value for the pointer, then `*data = NULL;` would be fine, as `realloc` accepts a null pointer.
- Test the result of `malloc` and `realloc` to see if they failed.
- Avoid writing code that uses the same object in the argument to `realloc` and the assignment of its result, as in `*data = realloc(*data, ckSize);`. When `realloc` fails, this loses the original address. That can be okay if all you are going to do when an error occurs is exit the program. However, if you want to continue the program in the face of an allocation error, you need to retain the original address so it can be freed later.

Answer (score 0):

In the standard C library we prefer to don't alloc memory and let the user alloc and free his memory himself, so you can take as parameter a already allocate **data and the size of the allocation, make sure to never overflow the given size and just fill the data.

If you want to allocate the memory youself don't take data as parameter, create your own pointer, malloc it then return it, if you encounteer an error fill the global variable errno and return NULL (free you pointer before return NULL), if success return the pointer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your second paragraph. If I do malloc in the function and then return the pointer, I don't need to free the memory. Therefore the user will need to free it, right ?