# What happens really when malloc?

Tags: c, process, malloc

`malloc` tries to reserve a memory block in my virtual memory, isn't it?
What happens if I request 3MB of virtual memory but only 2MB are free. 
Will the OS then provide more memory? So can virtual memory grow?

Comment: This is a very broad question that cannot be answered in a simple answer. Read up on memory management, heap management and virtual memory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: (Not that relevant but) but a great read >>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509714/i-can-use-more-memory-than-how-much-ive-allocated-with-malloc-why

Comment: Actually I just wanted to know whether the system takes care about the process and continuously feeding it with memory or whether the process must request memory "personally".

Comment: I believe the behavior is unexpected, it could result in a buffer overflow scenario. You should read up.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question. This is about requesting more virtual memory than available and a modern OS would handle that. The linked one is simply a writing beyond the allocated memory.

Comment: About the buffer overflow: malloc can return addresses which were already allocated by a previous malloc?

Comment: Regarding the second question (requesting 3 MB of virtual memory when only 2 MB are free): read about [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging)

Comment: The duplicate linked question does not provide an answer to my question at all.

Comment: @R_Kapp I request 3MB of virtual memory but only 2MB of virtual (not physical) memory are free.

Comment: In that event, in theory, you should get a NULL return. In practice, that's not exactly what happens due to settings in the OS that typically default to optimistically assume that the `malloc` worked until you try to use the pointer, when it will crash.

Comment: @R_Kapp so I get a pointer but I cannot use it because no memory is actually available?

Comment: @今天春天 On the buffer overflow, yes it might happen if your program keeps on doing malloc.

Comment: @今天春天: That is correct.

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped alot. So I can assume that malloc only returns null if the system sees no way to get more memory?