# Could allocation size of zero in malloc result in conflicting memory locations?

Tags: c, malloc, libc

So from the explanation of [`malloc(0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022335/whats-the-point-of-malloc0) question. I find it counterintuitive that the notion of the zero size of the allocated memory chunk when returning a not-NULL value. (concluded from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1073175/10362396))

Since, two malloc addresses cannot be the same, allocation that is returned should then take up at least one byte to guarantee that return value future calls to `malloc` does not collide with any `malloc(0)` in the current processs' lifetime.

Alternatively, it would imply that two mallocs—one with 0 and the other without—would in this instance return the same base address, which is conflicting as two memory locations with different size is not possible.

Comment: For something with implementation-specific behavior, if you want to know _why_ something does what it does, you have to ask the implementor(s).

Comment: You've overlooked of the uniqueness requirement. And it *does* take up at least one byte, because of its own overhead. It has to keep a length word somewhere, maybe more. Nothing in your link to suggest otherwise.

Comment: The man page for Posix `malloc` says that for a zero size it will either return `NULL` or a unique pointer.  My advice is to avoid using a size of zero.  If you want a unique pointer, use a size of 1.

Comment: The thing to remember is that the value passed to malloc is a minimum, the implementation is free to allocate more than the requested amount (and indeed generally must for bookkeeping purposes, even if that memory isn't available for the caller of malloc to use).

Comment: What are "conflicting memory locations"? `it would imply that two mallocs—one with 0 and the other without—would in this instance return the same base address` I do not follow, where is the implication? The malloc just have to not return that address. That something can happen doesn't mean it will happen. Malloc writers are writing it, they should not do it.

Comment: @KamilCuk Doing certain malloc operation would result in same base address, is what I meant here.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir "the implementation is free to allocate more than the requested amount". I remember now, this is what I read in "Understanding and Using C Pointers" by Richard Reese.

Comment: @tbhaxor Returning the same base address twice is impossible by the uniqueness requirement. You've been told all this above.

Comment: Exactly @user207421! Actually I think the same too. But then the allocated region size must not be zero, which defies [this](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MEM04-C.+Beware+of+zero-length+allocations).

Comment: @tbhaxor It *agrees* with 'this': "or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value".

Comment: @tbhaxor `malloc(0)` does not have to allocate any memory. Yes, it must return a unique pointer (or `NULL`), but it is completely up to the implementers how to achieve that. You are implying that allocating a small amount of memory is the only way. That is not correct. Even if the returned pointer is not `NULL`, it does not have to point at a usable address.

Comment: Calling `malloc(0)` twice in succession with MS VC results in two pointers that are 32 bytes apart.

Comment: @user207421 I meant "_may return a reference to a block of memory of size 0 instead of a null pointer_" from 'this'.

Comment: @user207421 "And it does take up at least one byte, because of its own overhead." --> No,  The overhead associated with returning non-_null pointers_ for size 0 calls can be 0 per call.  Recall the pointer returned can not be de-referenced, so it does not need to point to real memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Could allocation size of zero in malloc result in conflicting memory locations?

No.

Consider non-zero size calls.
2 successful calls `malloc(some_non-zero_value)`<sup>*1</sup> return different pointers.

Now look as size zero.  Allocating size zero is special and deserves careful digesting of the C spec.

With an allocation of size zero, 1 of 2 things happen:

- "If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is
  implementation-defined: either **a null pointer is returned** to indicate an error, or the behavior is **as if the size were some nonzero value**, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object."
  C23dr § 7.24.3 1

So if code does not receive a *null pointer* when allocating size zero, the pointer is **as if** it was `malloc(some_non-zero_value)`.  Multiple successful `malloc(some_non-zero_value)` are unique.

---

Since your code may tolerate a *null pointer* from `malloc(0)`, and multiple calls then may both return a *null pointer* and so lose the uniqueness attribute of different calls returning different pointers, always use a non-zero size to maintain uniqueness.

---

**Deeper**

"... allocation that is returned should then take up at least one byte to guarantee that return value future calls to malloc does not collide with any malloc(0) in the current processs' lifetime." --> "should then take up at least one byte" is not supported by the C spec.

Consider `malloc()` could return a pointer that does not actually point to real physical memory until accessed.  Since the caller of `malloc(0)` is prohibited from de-referencing the returned pointer, no physical memory is certainly used.

See [Why is malloc not "using up" the memory on my computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19991623/2410359)

---

<sup>*1</sup> Without a intervening `free()` of the first.

Comment: What's the rationale for allowing `malloc(0)` to be allowed to return non-null?

Comment: @Schwern I could see an implementation wanting to provide distinctive pointers when a `malloc(0)` failed and `malloc(0)` succeeded in older implementations and to maintain that going forward. The spec changed in C17 on this matter.  IMO the change still leads to some uncertainly and recommend to not call `malloc(0)` as it is a [rabbit hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_the_rabbit_hole) of spec history and implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @Schwern I am guessing here, but the rationale could simply be that there is no reason to disallow returning non-null. On the other hand, there is a good reason to require unique non-null pointers because otherwise it could give problems in subsequent calls to `free()`.

Comment: @Schwern From the [**Rationale for American National Standard for Information Systems - Programming Language - C**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/rationale/a.html#1-1) (italics in original): "The X3J11 charter clearly mandates the Committee to *codify common existing practice*.  ..."  There were likely different `malloc( 0 )` implementations prior to C being standardized where some would return `NULL` and some would return a non-`NULL` pointer that could not be safely dereferenced.

Comment: It looks like a defect in the standard. In practice, this definition prevents returning non-null value from `malloc(0)` because it forces the pointer to be unique with each call. The non-conforming implementation could simply return a cookie (i.e. a pointer to a static object) in such a case. Generating a unique pointer each time is too cumbersome thus any practical implementation would simply return `NULL` for in favor of simpler implementation.

Comment: @tstanisl Disagree with "Generating a unique pointer each time is too cumbersome", yet I really do not want too become [Alice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_the_rabbit_hole).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I dare to disagree. Returning an unique pointer for each malloc  is annoying and requires int-to-pointer magic. Moreover, it is painful in multithreading environment. I don't see why two `malloc(0)` are forbidden from returning the same non-null cookie pointer.

Comment: @tstanisl To return "same non-null cookie pointer" fails to follow "behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object".

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, It's obvious that it fails. I am just interested why the standard puts such a constraining requirement.

Comment: @tstanisl To standardize existing coding practices at the time of initial standardization.  When returning non-`NULL`, users expect different pointers.  It is a constraint, but not a difficult one for memory allocators to follow.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, when returning non-`NULL` from `malloc(0)`, a user only expects something that can be safely passed to `free()`. Those pointers do not point to *objects*. So there is no need for them to be unique because users want **objects** is have unique addresses. I still think that is a defect in the standard.

Comment: @tstanisl "a user _only_ expects something that can be safely passed to free()" --> Perhaps for some users, other may want uniqueness even with non-null pointers that are not pointing to objects.  The C spec certainly does not specify users' expectations.  I [still maintain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77428897/could-allocation-size-of-zero-in-malloc-result-in-conflicting-memory-locations/77429437?noredirect=1#comment136504104_77429437) that `malloc(0)` is best avoided and/or, as you suggest, assume little about that return value.

Comment: @tstanisl " I still think that is a defect in the standard." --> repairs to any `malloc(0)` defect may solve some issues yet risk breaking existing code bases.  Consider suggesting improvements to the C committee.